# ASP.NET account missing in WIN 10 Home

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, dcom

I can´t create/set up the ASP.NET (machine) account in my Windows 10 home edition. I need it to configure a DCOM wrapper. I follow all the instructions for IIS configuration from MS. Please help! Thanks in advance!

.NET Framework:4.0.30319; ASP.NET:4.6.1586.0

Comment: Please describe your exact problem

Comment: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Could not retrieve COM class generator for component with CLSID {F3D77DAE-6C14-426E-B56F-C550BDE8B09D} Due to the following error: 80070005 Access denied. (Exception  HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

Comment: Please add this problem to question text, while update whole definition to create [a  reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: the code is proven that works in other instances, the error is in the constructor of the class as follow:

    public B1WSHandler()
    {
        DIServerNode = (SBODI_Server.Node)new SBODI_Server.Node();
    }

Comment: ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource.

Comment: You followed none of the correct documentation. ASPNET account is gone for ever. Use IUSR instead if you still use anonymous authentication, or other proper account if you use other authentication methods. If you don't know IIS 6 and above, now you'd better start from a good enough book from scratch.